# Regrouping object list

Tags: django-templates

I'm attempting to group cities by country.

In my template the following works - without grouping:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
{{ item.country}}
{{ item.city }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, when I regroup:

```
{% regroup object_list by country as country_list %}
{% for item in country_list %}
{{ item.city }}
{% endfor %}
```

item.city is not rendered.

The ungrouped object list is:

```
<QuerySet [<Country: England>, <Country: France>, <Country: Germany>, <Country: Netherlands>]>
```

After grouping:

```
Country: [GroupedResult(grouper=<Country: England>, list=[<City: Liverpool>, <City: London>, <City: Manchester>]), GroupedResult(grouper=<Country: Germany>, list=[<City: Munich>])....]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

```html
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note the `.list` in the loop statetement
So for your chunk of code it seems that you should use

```html
{% regroup object_list by country as country_list %}
{% for country in country_list %}
    {% for city in country.list %}
        <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```